# How do i show component in blade?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

Why the code of my app is not working in Laravel?
If I set the address `/admin`, then everything works and shows the admin.blade.php template
and if I set `admin/one`, it shows admin.blade.php, but the material that is in the app is not shown

This is working:

```
Route::get('/admin','AdminController@index')->middleware(['auth', 'auth.admin']);
```

```
<body>
it's work
<div id="app">
    it's working
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
<script src="js/app.js">

</script>
</body>
```

but this is not:

```
Route::get('/admin/one','AdminController@index')->middleware(['auth', 'auth.admin']);
```

```
<body>
it's work
<div id="app">
    it's not working
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
<script src="js/app.js">

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: share controller's method also ?

Comment: after `/admin` all routes are for vue router route and vue router perhaps dont have `/admin/one`

Comment: Can you share what your `public function index()` looks like in your `AdminController.php`

Answer (score 1):

The point is that Laravel's and Vue routes are not the same.
Vue routes are kinda virtual. They only exist and work inside the browser.
Vue is used for single-page applications - aka SPA.

In order for this to work, you should change your admin route to match anything starting with "/admin"

so, your route shall be like:

```php
Route::get('/admin/{param?}','AdminController@index')->where('param', '(.*)')->middleware(['auth', 'auth.admin']);
```

and it should return a blade view with your vue application.
Your Vue application then should display the requested page based on what route was requested. That's what vue-router was made for.
And all or your admin pages and layouts should be handled by Vue.
And in your Vue's resources/js/router/index.js ( I suppose you use Laravel Mix )

```js
export const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: MainLayoutComponent,
        redirect: { name: 'home' },
        children: [
            {
                path: 'home',
                name: 'home',
                component: AdminHome,
                meta: {
                    title: 'Main Page'
                },
            },
        ]
    }
];
const router = new Router({
    routes,
    base: '/admin', 
    mode: 'history',
});
```